# error building image: error building stage: failed to execute command: waiting for process to exit: exit status 10

Tags: kubernetes, db2, gitlab-ci-runner, cicd, kaniko

I have a CI/CD job that is supposed to build me a DB2 image from a local harbor directory using kaniko.

Once build this image is published on this harbor directory.

Here's my DB2 container build job:

```
db2-build:
  extends: .kaniko_job
  tags:
    - kubernetes
  stage: container-build
  image:
    name: gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:debug
    entrypoint: [""]
  variables:
    CONTEXT_DIR: "container/db2"
    CONTAINERFILE_PATH: "container/db2/Containerfile"
    IMAGE_PATH: "${CI_PROJECT_PATH}/db2"
    KANIKO_ARGS: "--verbosity=debug --build-arg PJ_USER_USERNAME=${PJ_USER_USERNAME} --build-arg PJ_USER_PASSWORD=${PJ_USER_PASSWORD} --build-arg WAS_VERSION=${WAS_VERSION} --build-arg FRAMEWORK_VERSION=${FRAMEWORK_VERSION} --build-arg CIOBS_VERSION=${CIOBS_VERSION} --build-arg RNRPP_HOSTNAME=${RNRPP_HOSTNAME} --build-arg CACLR_HOSTNAME=${CACLR_HOSTNAME}"
  needs: ["maven-build-test"]
  rules:
    - if: $task == "container-build"
    - if: $task == null && $MANUAL_CONTAINER_BUILD == "false" && $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "main"
```

And here's my kaniko job from which the DB2 job inherits:

```
   .kaniko_job:
      stage: container-build
      tags:
        - kubernetes
      image:
        name: arhs-harbor.arhs-developments.com/library/kaniko:1.9.1
        entrypoint: [""]
      timeout: 1h
      variables:
        IMAGE_PATH: ""
        CONTEXT_DIR: "${CI_PROJECT_DIR}"
        KANIKO_ARGS: ""
        CONTAINERFILE_PATH: "$CONTEXT_DIR/Containerfile"
      script:
        - mkdir -p /kaniko/.docker
        - /kaniko/executor version
        - echo "{\"auths\":{\"$CI_REGISTRY\":{\"username\":\"$CI_REGISTRY_USER\",\"password\":\"$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD\"}}}" > /kaniko/.docker/config.json
        - echo "${KANIKO_ARGS}"
        - |
          /kaniko/executor $KANIKO_ARGS \
            --ignore-path=/usr/bin/ping \
            --ignore-path=/usr/bin/newgidmap \
            --ignore-path=/usr/bin/newuidmap \
            --ignore-path=/usr/sbin/arping \
            --ignore-path=/usr/sbin/clockdiff \
            --cache-copy-layers \
            --cache \
            --cache-ttl 24h \
            --context $CONTEXT_DIR \
            --dockerfile $CONTAINERFILE_PATH \
            --destination $CI_REGISTRY/$IMAGE_PATH:$CI_COMMIT_SHA \
            --destination $CI_REGISTRY/$IMAGE_PATH:$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG
```

This job used to work perfectly, but for the past 3 weeks I've been getting this error:

> **+ db2stop force SQL6037N  START or STOP DATABASE MANAGER timeout value was reached. error building image: error building stage: failed
> to execute command: waiting for process to exit: exit status 10
> Cleaning up project directory and file based variables 00:01 ERROR:
> Job failed: command terminated with exit code 10**

This error only occurs on the Gitlab runner. FYI, I use the kubernetes executor and my runner runs via a pod

I'm trying to debug by trying to retrieve the logs, but I can't find any information or apparent error to tell me more about this pipeline failure.

However, locally, the container is building, so there's no problem. I even tried to empty the DB2 caches generated, but no way.

I also tried the debug version (as used above), I tried to downgrade and upgrade the kaniko version but no way.

If anyone can help me understand this error or get more information, I'd love to hear from you.

**UPDATE** link to my log files :

- db2diag.log : [https://sharetxt.live/db2diaglog](https://ctxt.io/2/AABQPfuRFQ)
- db2inst1.nfy : [enter link description here](https://ctxt.io/2/AABQreFlEg)

Comment: Multiple causes can trigger SQL6037N in Db2-LUW, so check both the db2diag.log file (in the Db2-instance home directory, for example  if the name of the Db2-instance is db2inst1, then look in (relative to the server container) ~db2inst1/sqllib/db2dump/DIAG0000/db2diag.log,  and in the same directory the *.nfy file (admin notification log).

Comment: I've retrieved the two files from the runner and tried to analyze them, but I can't see any apparent error that would let me know the reason for the error

Comment: UPDATE : I shared my log files

Comment: The container uses a non-root version of the Db2 v10.5.0.5 (released December 2014), with only 2 cores,  maybe foolish, as  other components (e.g. base o/s, system policies, firewall settings, o/s configuration) may have changed substantially or did not exist in 2014. If it worked it the past, and fails now, it's because some component has changed/reconfigured.  Try Db2-server build (e.g. v11.5.0.8) , or systematically comparing all operating system (security policies/firewall settings) between working and failing environments.  This is not programming. It's configuration.

Comment: I have upgraded the db2 v10.5.0.5 image version to ibmcom/db2:11.5.8.0, but I have a script running via my Containerfile that executes this db2start command which is not recognized by the new DB2 image version. Does the script need to be readapted? 

/scripts/init-db.sh: line 7: db2start: command not found
error building image: error building stage: failed to execute command: waiting for process to exit: exit status 127

Comment: Your comment, asks a new question. That's not how stackoverflow is supposed to work. One question, one answer.  Your new symptom is FAQ, it means your script has to dot in the correct db2profile as its first step before running any db2 action, via something like `. ~db2inst1/sqllib/db2profile`. For anything else, create a new stackoverflow question.

Comment: Yes, you're right